# json load fails because of escape double quots

Tags: json, python-3.x, double-quotes

```
test ='{"desc": "{\"OS\":\"N\",\"DR\":\"N\",\"SNAPSHOT\":\"N\",\"SERVICENAME\":\" MariaDB \"}"}'
test2 = json.loads(test)
```

---

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 13 (char 12)

How can I get out of this hell?

Comment: Whence is this JSON string?  The escaped double quotes look to be perhaps something you copied from your Python terminal.  The double quotes shouldn't be escaped, this is the problem.

Comment: If `test` was a raw string, typed as `test = r'{...}'` It would load, but then the value of `test2['desc']` would be another JSON string.  The solution is to write a valid JSON string to begin with.  I suspect the string was cut and pasted from a file, but JSON syntax and Python syntax are not the same and a raw string represents the file content more accurately.

Comment: That string is from the api.
I have no control over that string.
Can I change \" to \'?

Comment: I was able to replace it using raw type. Thank you,  Mark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
test ='{"desc": "{\"OS\":\"N\",\"DR\":\"N\",\"SNAPSHOT\":\"N\",\"SERVICENAME\":\" MariaDB \"}"}'

test2 = test.replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}')
test2 = eval(test2)

print(test2)
print(type(test2))
```

Prints

```
{'desc': {'OS': 'N', 'DR': 'N', 'SNAPSHOT': 'N', 'SERVICENAME': ' MariaDB '}}
<class 'dict'>
```